# Objective C componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, string

I'm trying to pass a url from JavaScript to Objective C using window.location.
My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var str = "http://sampleurl:8080/abc";
window.location.href = "jscall:myapp:"+str;
```

In Objective C:

```
NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

if ([components count] > 1 &&
    [(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"jscall"]) {
    if([(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
    {
      NSLog([components objectAtIndex:2]); //this returns just "http"

        NSString* str1 = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString* str2 = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:3];            
        NSString* str3 = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:4];
        str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:@":"];
        str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:str3];           
        str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@":"];
        self.jsLbl.text = [str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
        //The output of this is "http://sampleurl:8080/abc"
    }
    return NO;
}
```

If I use just

```
  NSString* str1 = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:2];
```

I am getting only "http".
How can I restrict the string to limit componentsSeparatedByString by 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't explicitly split only the first two occurrences of ':', but what you could easily do is just use another method as you know exactly what the string is up to the point of the 'http'. It would be safe to just do one of the following.

```
NSString *urlString = [requestString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"jscall:myapp:" withString:@""];
```

or

```
NSUInteger prefixLength = @"jscall:myapp:".length;
NSString *urlString = [requestString substringFromIndex:prefixLength];
```

The second one is more reliable incase for some reason there were multiple occurrences of that string in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to parse a URL.  Use `NSURLComponents`.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't usually do:

```
var str = "http://sampleurl:8080/abc";
window.location.href = "jscall:myapp:"+str;
```

you'd instead use a custom scheme so your code can check what to do with the URL, like:

```
var str = "myapplink://sampleurl:8080/abc";
window.location.href = str;
```

and your obj-c code would check the scheme and then use the url, replacing the scheme with something else if you need it to.